# не могу понять часть решения в задачах

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, python-2.x

изучаю алгоритмы по книге "Грокаем алгоритмы",
В главе, где рассказывается про быструю сортировку, был приведён такой код:

```
def quick_sort(arr):
    if len(arr) < 2:
        return arr
    else:
        pivot = arr[0]
        less = [i for i in arr[1:] if i <= pivot]
        greater = [i for i in arr[1:] if i > pivot]
        return quick_sort(less) + [pivot] + quick_sort(greater)
```

Не могу понять, как работает то, что в else, никогда такого не видел. Сначала подумал, что это из-за того что в книге все примеры кода на python 2, а я пишу на python 3, но нет, работает как надо, может кто-нибудь кратко объяснить? Или скинуть ссылки, где об этом можно прочитать? Понимаю в целом, что происходит в этих строках, но [i for i in] за гранью моего понимания.

Comment: Это называется list comprehension. И если у вас проблемы именно с этой частью кода, то нужно и задавать вопрос именно по этой части и приводить именно эту часть, а не "как работает, то что в else". Автобиографию в заголовке тоже не надо писать

Comment: [Видео про генераторы списков в Python 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zBTBr6XdZo&list=PLQAt0m1f9OHvv2wxPGSCWjgy1qER_FvB6&index=48)

Answer (score 0):

То с чем вы столкнулись - является *генератором*. `i` перед `for` означает что генератор будет возвращать значение `i`. Таким образом можно сгенерировать список. Несколько примеров:

```
>>> [i for i in range(4)]
#Вывод: [0, 1, 2, 3]

>>> [i.upper() for i in ['a', 'b', 'c']]
#Вывод: ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Генераторы довольно сложно понять. Поэтому, возможно, вы будете долго разбираться с ними. Для начала прочтите [это](https://skillbox.ru/media/code/generatory_python_chto_eto_takoe_i_zachem_oni_nuzhny/).